# Getting Error : There is no simulation script. Please check that your scripts are in user-files/ simulations Press any key to continue . .

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I am facing this problem, when executing gatling batch file using command prompt.

GATLING_HOME is set to "G:\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.1.4"
There is no simulation script. Please check that your scripts are in user-files/
simulations
Press any key to continue . . .

I have downloaded new Gatling copy gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.1.4 from http://gatling.io/download/
And trying to run computerdatabase Simulation, getting error message.

Is there any way to run simulation other than using batch file through Command prompt?

Thanks

Comment: Hi,
Did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can run it with

- The [sbt plugin](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/extensions/sbt_plugin.html)
- The [maven plugin](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/extensions/maven_plugin.html)
- As standalone application. You find an example in the [Maven archetype](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/extensions/maven_archetype.html)
- Run with Jenkins and the [Gatling-Jenkins plugin](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/extensions/jenkins_plugin.html)

Note that the above documentation links use the Gatling version 2.1.7. Yet the plugins exist as well in older versions (like 2.1.4) and will probably continue in later versions as well - just replace the version number on http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/.

Answer (score 0):

The cause may be the lack of **JAVA_HOME** environment variable.